# GnuWin32 or Cygwin - from a programmers point of view

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin, emulation, gnuwin32

For a programmer with Linux skills and a love of the command line, what is better to use on Windows - Cygwin or GnuWin32?

I tried to find a good comparison or a list of differences but couldn't find anything remotely complete. Also, I wondered whether this should be a superuser.com question, but decided against it, because I'm asking precisely for use of the tool for a programmer.

I'd like to know the common pitfalls and restrictions of each of the solutions. Interoperability with windows is an important issue, for my main development is done in MSVC...

Comment: Perhaps not SuperUser.com, but programmers.stackexchange.com for sure.

Comment: I see 1000 tagged questions on SO, with 14 for gnuwin32. Go with the community.

Comment: @Eric, that may just mean that there's almost 100 times more problems with Cygwin ;)

Comment: Ha. In seriousness, my experience with CygWin has been good, one I figured out the right way to set it up: http://wilsonericn.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/cygwin-setup-gotchas/ I'm not providing an answer, though, because I've never heard of gnuwin32, and don't know what MSVC is.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but since you mention the command line, are you trying to do scripting?  If so, save yourself some trouble and use Powershell or python for windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is absolutely no contest

### GnuWin32 does not include **Bash**

This is a critical part of the Cygwin distribution. Switching from `cmd.exe` to Bash was a huge boon to my productivity. `cmd.exe` is cripped in comparison to Bash.

### GnuWin32 is old

Many program go **years** without being updated.

- `tar` 2003
- `coreutils` 2005
- `zlib` 2005
- `make` 2006
- `wget` 2008

I would not use GnuWin32 unless I had no other choice.