# Where to take sh for Windows suitable to build Hadoop?

Tags: windows, hadoop, build, sh, gnuwin32

To compile Hadoop under Windows it is said to have `sh` program
(in [BUILDING.txt](http://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/58590f/BUILDING.txt#L285-L286) file), which is said to be contained in `GnuWin32`.
Unfortunately, I can’t find one there, for example, in [Sh-Utils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

Where can I take `sh.exe`, required for Hadoop compilation?

Answer (score 0):

They are telling you to get `sh.exe` from GnuWin32 because they don’t know shit
about Windows. Here are some things wrong with GnuWin32:

- GnuWin32 is hosted on SourceForge, which is a [known badware site](http://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Badware-risks#sourceforgenet), and
  won’t even load if you are using uBlock Add-on
- GnuWin32 doesn’t even provide `sh.exe` [as you can see from their own site](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/faq.html#How_do_I_run_shell_scripts)
- Even if they did provide it, you wouldn’t want it. Most of GnuWin32 tools are
  [years out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10876188)

Just do the sane thing and get Cygwin.

Comment: This is the question. Had the creators of `BUILDING.TXT` something in mind?

Comment: I don't understan, whether I am the first to compile Hadoop under Windows? They have this note about Cygwin for many versions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, sh.exe is not part of GnuWin32. My suggestion is to install git and set the environment path to use git binaries. Git includes all needed *nix like tool in windows for hadoop compilation.

Git download url: http://git-scm.com/download/win